# R :How to extract a column of a time series object in

Tags: time, time-series

I'm not familiar with the object of class time series in R.

I work with the data **EuStockMarkets**. This time series is composed of 4 columns. How can I work only with the column  number 3 (named `CAC`) ?

```
donnee =data(EuStockMarkets)
```

Comment: I tried    donnee[,3] or     donnee$CAC but it does not run

Comment: donneeCAC = EuStockMarkets[,3]

Answer (score 2):

It should work, I tried the following and got the values

```
eu_stocks<-EuStockMarkets
EuStockMarkets[,3]
eu_stocks[,3]
summary(EuStockMarkets[,3])
```

Min. 1st Qu.  Median    Mean 3rd Qu.    Max. 
   1611    1875    1992    2228    2274    4388

I even tried to plot and successful.

```
ts.plot(EuStockMarkets[,3], col = 1:4, 
        xlab = "Year", ylab = "Index Value", 
        main = "Major European Stock Indices, 1991-1998")
```